# How do I verify the total rows inserted to a table?

Tags: cassandra

I have table in cassandra with 9 columns
primary key ((column1, column2),forecastdate

I have inserted 10,000 records in this table by reading from cassandra v1.0.12 and writing to cassandra v3.x using a java program having insert queries

To validate data in target cassandra 3 host, I want check num of records inserted in ver 3.x

If I run select count(*) from table_name;
it returns me huge number of 2,109,761

While nodetool cfstats shows : Number of Keys (estimated) as 6,450

Want to understand how can I validate data after inserting into new cass version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The values provided by `cfstats` are not accurate before performing a compaction or a flush.

> The nodetool cfstats command provides statistics about one or more tables. It's updated when SSTables change through compaction or flushing.

[source](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html)

To count the number of rows in a table I recommend the free tool `DSBulk`. Indeed a count(*) will timeout pretty quickly with a bit of volume.

```bash
dsbulk count --stats.modes global -k myKeyspace -t myTable
```

[DSBulk reference documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/countOptions.html)

Comment: I am not using datastax version of cassandra and for I am starting cqlsh with timeout option 
cqlsh --request-timeout=3600

Comment: dsbulk works with any cassandra version and is OSS and free to use. Got you with the request timeout. Cqlsh operates a count with paging where as DSbulk leverages a token ranged-query for performance boost.

Comment: dsbulk count seems not working with Cassandra ver 1.0.12, does anyone know how dsbulk can be used with Cassandra ver 1.x ?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in CQL function `COUNT()` will return the number of partitions in the table, not just what you last inserted (provided it doesn't timeout).

Unless you have a way of filtering just the data you inserted, any method you use to count will return all the records in the table.

As a side note, the number of keys reported by `nodetool cfstats` is just an estimate. If you're interested, I've explained why it is not an accurate count in [Why COUNT() is bad in Cassandra](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/).

In any case, a more reliable way to count records in Cassandra is with the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html) tool. It is open-source so it's free to use. It was originally designed for bulk-loading data to and exporting data from a Cassandra cluster as a scalable solution for [the cqlsh `COPY` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-to).

DSBulk has a `count` command that provides the same functionality as the CQL `COUNT()` function but has optimisations that break up the table scan into small range queries so doesn't suffer from the same problems as brute-force counting.

DSBulk is quite simple to use and only takes a few minutes to setup. First, you need to download the binaries from [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#bulk-loader) then unpack the tarball. For details, see the [DSBulk Installation Instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/install/dsbulkInstall.html).

Once you've got it installed, you can count the partitions in a table with one command:

```
$ cd path/to/dsbulk_installation
$ bin/dsbulk count -h <node_ip> -k ks_name -t table_name
```

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Docs - [Counting data in tables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkCountData.html)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)

Comment: dsbulk count seems not working with Cassandra ver 1.0.12, does anyone know how dsbulk can be used with Cassandra ver 1.x ?

Comment: A friendly advice that this is a different question to the one you originally posted. We generally don't respond to follow up questions in the comment section because it becomes a never-ending thread so please post a new [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra) question and we'd be happy to respond there. Cheers!